# Header not showing after changing the language to Arabic

Tags: magento2

For adding the language switcher for a website, I created an additional `Arabic store view`. 
When I select the `Arabic` language in dropdown, the store view changes to Arabic, but the entire header part is not there.

I am using the Homepage style 21 of SM Market Theme. When I inspect the header section of both pages, the class names of body tag is different. English store view is showing `header-21-style`, where as in the Arabic store view the class name is showing `header-1-style`. Not sure if this is the reason. It would be very helpful if someone could help me to fix the header. I need to know if I have missed out anything. Thank you in advance.
[image: screenshot of home page of English store view]

Comment: it's showing different header for both language(store view wise) which have option in admin for SM Market Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's showing different header for both language(store view wise) which have option in admin for SM Market Theme.

> Store > Configuration > SM Market > select your store view

then check which header is set.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Earlier when I checked the header area I read it as `Header Style 21`. I just changed it and it is loading properly. Thank you so much